# How to Make Windows Network Visible to Linux Server Box?

Tags: samba, centos6, windows

Salvete!  I have a machine running CentOS 6.2.  In the GUI, if I click on "Network", I get a messagebox saying: "Unable to mount location - Failed to retrieve share list from server"

I can ping the machine from my windows computer on the network, and I can also ping the windows computer from the linux server.  My Windows computers on the network all have their file sharing turned on and are able to see each other.

Samba is configured and running, nmb is running, and I can connect just fine to the box from my windows computer using Putty.  In samba, I have specified the workgroup name.

How do I make the Windows Network visible to the Linux machine?  I don't want to *mount a share*, I only want the Linux machine to see that there other computers on the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you are trying to achieve exactly: Do you want to mount a "share" from the windows box on the Linux machine?

For that you do only need the samba client, not a samba daemon.

To mount the share try `mount -t cifs -o <username>,<password> //<servername>/<sharename> /mnt/point/` or any of the other methods described at [Connecting to a Samba Share](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-samba-connect-share.html).

[Nautilus and Konqueror provide options to browse a Windows network](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/WindowsShares).

In Konqueror, Go -> Network folders -> Samba Shares

In Nautilus, Places -> Network -> Windows Network

Comment: No, I want to be able to open "Network" on the linux machine and see all the computers in the workgroup.  The linux machine, right now, cannot find any computers in the workgroup.

Comment: That isn't the same as mounting a share, I don't think.  "Mounting a Share" is the same as "mapping a network drive" in windows terms, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Well, after fiddling around with the samba configuration, it began to work.  We have three workgroups here, and now I can see all of the computers in each workgroup from within the "Network" of the Linux machine's Places.  I am even able to see the Macs on the network, too.  I have retraced all of my steps but can't figure out now how to get it to *not work*!

If I figure out what I did, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is been my experience as well.  I am sure there is a fix in there, but I am unable to figure out what change "fixed" the issue.  let us know what you find.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for CentOS or other flavors of Linux.  But in order for other Windows machines to be able to see each other in "Network Neighborhood", "My Network Places" etc, file and/or printer sharing has to be enabled.  If the server service isn't running on the windows box, the services will not respond to network browsing requests (this is a high level explanation).  Can your windows boxes see each other?

Comment: That is a legitimate thing to mention, but yes, there is no problem there.  I would feel *really* dumb if my windows computers didn't have sharing turned on!  I will edit my question and mention the fact.

Comment: Most admins would know to check, but you can't always assume on here. :) We have a few windows boxes that talk back to a RHEL box.  Periodically we have trouble getting the windows boxes to see the RHEL in "My network places". But regardless of this, the shares still map and the users are able to move files around.  Just curious what you are trying to solve with making sure the windows boxes are visible to Linux?

Comment: And, you never know - it is very possible to take something for granted and completely forget to check on it.  I needed the network shares so I could load a package from one of them.