# How to Enable Full-Rights File-Browsing on /?

Tags: linux, networking, samba, file-sharing, centos6.2

Now, I know there are lots of samba questions (about 1400) on ServerFault, and I have browsed through about half of them at least, and not been able to use any of the answers to solve my problem.

We are installing CentOS 6.2 on a new, blank machine - clean install; it will run as a network server to host Asterisk.

*I want to configure the machine so I have full, administrative access to root (I mean the "/" root) from my Windows workstation.*

This will enable me to use my own, comfortable machine (and Notepad++) to edit all the configuration files.  In other words, I should be able to open `\\mylinux\etc\samba\` in Windows Explorer and then have full rights to edit `smb.conf` with my Windows Text Editor.

I have this working very well with CentOS 4, but can't get it working in CentOS 6.2.  In the older OS version, there was a GUI for everything, but now I need to learn and do everything from the CLI.  I still use the GUI for a few things that I haven't learned how to do form the CLI yet, so I will still make references to the GUI in my notes here.

Now that you know my problem and my goal, here are some details:

- `smb` is running and installed and set to runlevel 35.
- `nmb` is running and set to runlevel 35.
- the firewall is wide-open on eth0 and `network` is ON (I ran this command: `iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0 -j ACCEPT`)
- I have added my own user account on the linux box to the `root` group.
- that user account has the same username and password as my Windows computer.
- samba is configured to know the name of my Windows workgroup
- I am able to ping `\\mylinux` from `\\mywindows` just fine, and vice-versa, also.
- If I open `Network` in `\\mylinux`, I get an error saying: "Failed to retrieve share list from server" which I posted about [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/390914/how-to-make-windows-network-visible-to-linux-server-box).
- If I do a `net view` from `\\mywindows`, then it does not see `\\mylinux` at all.
- samba is configured to share the root drive:

.

```
[root]
comment = Root Directory
path = /
valid users = @root all root group
invalid users = None
writeable = yes
browseable = yes
```

- also, in `/etc/samba/smbusers.conf`, I have made my entry:

  `myuser = myuser`

Now, you would think that I could access the linux share at this point.  But when, from my Windows computer, I try to map the path `\\mylinux\root\`, I get an error saying the destination does not exist.  On my old linux machine, I am able to browse even to `\\oldlinux\` and get a list of shares.  I can't seem to duplicate the functionality!

**[EDIT]**

Okay, I disabled the firewall completely, and now I can browse the files wherever I want to go.  What remains is the permissions now to edit a file like smb.conf.  In other words, my user account that I use to browse the files, which is in the `root` group, also needs `root` permissions.  How do I get that?

Comment: This is a really, really, really bad idea from a security POV.  Also, samba will occasionally screw up file permissions, which makes this even worse.  Please don't do this.  Install WinSCP or something, but don't try to manage a production server over samba.

Comment: @devicenull - You are right, and I agree with you completely.  However, I am safely behind a firewall, and will only be using this kind of access from within my LAN.  And there is no risk in-house for security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it!  It took two things:
- Disable selinux
- uncomment the line in smb.conf for

```
username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
```

And, in smbusers.conf, I added `root = myuser`
then, run the command:

```
smbpasswd -a myuser
smbpasswd -e myuser
service smb restart
```

Now I can connect to the machine from my windows computer, browse the files in root, and edit them with my favourite text editor on my windows computer.

Just a note for all - I do understand it is a security risk working the procedures that I am working, but I am behind a secure firewall-router, and will only be administering the machine in this fashion from within the LAN.

**For CentOS7**

In CentOS 7, it denies ntlm authentication for root access by default - which means you cannot connect with a root account - unless you add this to the `[global]` section of smb.conf:

```
ntlm auth = yes
```

And if you *want* to use the smbusers file, add this to the same global section in smb.conf:

```
username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
```

Then you can create that file, and add this:

```
root = myusername
```

Comment: Please could you mark your answer as accepted, so that others know that this is the solution.

Comment: This doesn't work on Centos7.  Something is different; there isn't any smbusers.conf, so I don't know what to do now.

Answer (score 2):

Samba maps your access to a Unix user account on the server, and the normal permissions for that user are enforced. This is therefore the same as granting a Unix user write access to these files. You either need to actually be the `root` user (i.e. act as the owner of the files, which has write permission), or you need to be in a group which has group write permissions to the files. The latter is (marginally) preferable, so add yourself to the `root` group and change the file permissions to allow group writes. (I'm assuming that you are aware of the security implications of doing this.)

Comment: thanks for answering.  I do understand the security risks.  In my original problem, my user *was* a member of the root group.  However, I did manage to solve the problem - see my answer, too!