# Unable to access Samba fileshare on CentOS 7 from Windows 7 on AD Domain

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, samba, centos7

I'm trying to stand up a new CentOS 7 server running Samba and I'm unable to get access to the shared directories from my Windows 7 local machine.  As I'm not super familiar with CentOS 7, I followed the [tutorial here](http://www.hexblot.com/blog/centos-7-active-directory-and-samba) and can login and SSH into the server with my AD account and have access to the folder on the server with that same account.  When I try to hit the server from my Windows 7 machine, I get: "Logon failure: unknown username or bad password."

Here is my smb.conf file:

```
[global]
    workgroup = MYDOMAINLOCAL
    server string = Samba Server Version %v for CRL publishing
    hosts allow = 127. 10.0.
    interfaces = lo ens160 10.0.0.0\16

    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    log level = 3
    max log size = 50

    security = ads
    encrypt passwords = yes
    passdb backend = tdbsam
    realm = MYDOMAIN.LOCAL

    load printers = no
    cups options = raw
    printcap name = /dev/null

[IT]
    comment = IT Share
    path = /data/IT
    public = no
    writable = yes
    guest ok = no
    valid users = @"itdept@mydomain.local"
```

I'm at a loss at this point and I've spent the past several hours scouring the internet for any answer to no avail.

Other things I've done:

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=samba
# chcon -t samba_share_t /data/IT
# groups myusername@mydomain.local
myusername@mydomain.local: itdept@mydomain.local
```

Comment: Likely not the issue, and you've probably already checked, but have you confirmed that your win7 box has an IP that falls within your allowed host range?

Comment: Also, what method are you using to connect from the windows side?

Comment: Have you already joined the CentOS server to your AD domain?

Comment: Yes.  I can login and ssh in with my AD account

Comment: Yes, my win7 box has a valid IP in the same range and can ping the server.

Comment: I'm just trying to hit it from the run dialog with \\servername\IT.  I've also tried accessing it the same way from windows explorer

Comment: Here is another stab in the dark, is the time on both your windows and linux systems 100% correct?

Comment: Both are sync'd to the DC and showing as correct.  It did occur to me as I was driving home that I added myself to the AD group that I'm trying to grant access to and haven't yet rebooted my Windows box so it could be that Windows isn't passing along the correct info, but I'm inclined to think not.  Will test when I get to work in the morning.

Comment: Tested to make sure it wasn't the windows box and had another admin test from their AD joined Mac - neither of us can get in.  Still hoping for any suggestions on this

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I have the same problem.  I solved it for CentOS 5.5 (https://serverfault.com/questions/391076/how-to-enable-full-rights-file-browsing-on/391245#391245), but now that I've upgraded to version 6, I am stuck.